Pagination in TabBarView with NestedScrollView and SliverAppBar Snapping - Conflicting Behaviors
I'm trying to implement pagination within a TabBarView using NestedScrollView and SliverAppBar for a snapping effect. Here's the breakdown:
NestedScrollView:
headerSliverBuilder:
SliverOverlapInjector: Ensures overlapping behavior between SliverAppBar and inner scrollers.
SliverAppBar: Configured for floating and snapping behavior, along with title customization.
TabBarView:
Each tab contains a custom scrollable widget (without a controller) as the first sliver.
SliverOverlapInjector: Again, for overlapping behavior.
Pagination Logic:
I add a listener to detect when a tab reaches the end of its content (using widget.controller?.position.pixels and widget.controller?.position.maxScrollExtent).
Upon reaching the end, I trigger pagination by calling widget.fetchList with appropriate parameters.
The Problem:
Some sources suggest using separate controllers for the custom scrollable widgets within TabBarView.
However, doing so disrupts the intended snapping behavior of the SliverAppBar in NestedScrollView's headerSliverBuilder.
Question:
Is there a way to achieve both pagination within individual tabs and the snapping SliverAppBar functionality?
Has anyone encountered this conflict and found a solution?
Can you elaborate on what approaches you've tried to implement pagination within the TabBarView? Were you using a separate ScrollController for each custom scrollView within the tabs?
